# Multiple jQuery Event Listeners on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to learn how to write better jQuery code that is neater and more extensible. Most tutorials always, for the sake of convenience, use ideal case scenarios.

One of these cases are event listeners on a page. These listeners add up the more a user interacts with a page, which can cause problems, so as in this case.

**JS**

```
/* Adding list item (Click of Button) */
  $(document.body).on('click','#submit-item',function(e) {
    var buttonText = $(this).attr('value');

    if(buttonText == 'Add Item') {
      var productName = $(this).siblings('.form-group').children('input[name="product_name"]').val();
      var productDesc = $(this).siblings('.form-group').children('textarea[name="product_description"]').val();

      $('.list-group-items').append('<li class="list-group-item">' + productName + '<span class="hidden-product-desc">' + productDesc + '</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><input type="hidden" name="select_products[]" value="'+ productName +'|'+ productDesc +'"/></li>');
      $('.product_form').slideUp();
      alert('Item added!');
      buttonText = '';
      productName = '';
      productDesc = '';
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

  });
```

The above listens for a click event on a button and adds an item to the list. The first time this works fine. If the user adds another item and clicks the button, it then adds the item twice and so on. The tenth click would then result in 10 identical items being added to the list.

**What I've done so far:**

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
```

I  thought that these would prevent this problem.

I've also tried adding ".off()" after the target like so:

```
$(document.body).off().on('click','#submit-item',function(e) {
   // code here
});
```

This however breaks editing and deleting functionality on each item, which I built.

I'd like to know if there is a common practice that is being used to tackle this problem.

Comment: what happens above your code example?

Comment: This is rather poor code design than event listener issue.
If you provide fiddle example where people can examine the problem it would be easier to help

Comment: Try:  `.off('click', '#submit-item')`  `off` with no args will remove all event handlers, which you probably don't want.

Comment: @kidwon I absolutely agree. I put this down to my lack of knowledge. What kind of learning resources are there that do not use best case scenarios?

Comment: Never have an event handler that looks at the caption of the button - this is very bad.  The client might want to change the caption or maybe localise it and your code will suddenly stop working.  Add a class to the button, or much better still, add a single handler to each button.

Comment: Well I speak from experience, don't know of good resources, but there are 2 types of listeners. Delegated and direct.
Also the only reason I can think of delegating listening of unique id selected element event is the element being dynamic itself.
Otherwise attach the listener directly to the element.
Finally if you somehow duplicate element with the same ids that is bad practice, ids are meant to be unique so use class instead

Comment: So what you want is to avoid duplicates right?

Comment: Avoid duplicate IDs, yes, always.  Use class names rather than IDs if you're dynamically adding multiple items.  (or some fudge where you have a counter etc if you *really* need an ID).

Comment: Delegated `parent.on('click', 'elem_selector', function(){})` and direct `elem.on('click', function(){})`
Delegated listener is used to avoid multiple direct listeners of same event elements

Comment: @freedomn-m Agreed. I've changed the IDs to classes.

Comment: What eventually worked was the using one() instead of on()

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen that is good but in future understand the event tools that jQuery provides and how they work and you are going to use not only the one that circumstantially works but the one that is meant for the situation.
Knowing how they work will make your code design better

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen I dont understand the reason for this question? You asked for a more optimal way of using jquery. In the comments people have expressed their knowledge that the use of delegates in this case is not the best way of doing this and even if it is not a rather big one it can still cause performance issues if you have a large html since you start from the DOM body. There are several soloutions here but as others explained the use of delegates is not optimal when the element you attach the event to is loaded

Comment: @Ra3IDeN I haven't come across delegates before. I'll do more reading on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you assign the click event to the btn that you want clicked?

```
$(".buyItembtn").on("click", function(event){
   //do something

   event.stopPropagation();
   event.preventDefault();
})

$(".removeItemBtn").on("click", function(event){
   //do something

   event.stopPropagation();
   event.preventDefault();
})


alt:

$("#submit-item .buyItembtn").on("click", function(event){
   //do something

   event.stopPropagation();
   event.preventDefault();
})

$("#submit-item .removeItemBtn").on("click", function(event){
   //do something

   event.stopPropagation();
   event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: The second argument of the .on() is the target element.

Comment: @MarcusChristiansen The second argument is the filter selector (ie the item(s) under the first selector).. which is is optional - the above syntax is correct.

Comment: the second argument is optional, you can to it like this or you can add the target as the second parameter. look here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @freedomn-m I usually use the specific event listener that I need but I read in a forum that the on() is preferable in these kind of scenarios.

Comment: It depends on when the element is created related to when the `.on` is called.  If your button exists at the start, then use `$("#btn").click(...` or `$("#btn").on("click", ..` - **but** if you create the button *after* you've called `on` then yes, use `$("body").on("#btn", "click"...`.   In this case it looks like you're adding items, but the button is already there - so use the format in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct code is:

```
$( document.body).on( "click",'#submit-item', function( event ) {
 // code here
  $( this ).off( event );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use event namespacing and add/remove just specific listeners.

```
$( "p" ).on( "test.something", function( event ) {
  alert( event.namespace );
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/